# Using Custom Metadata Type in Email Template

Tags: email-template, customsetting, custom-metadata

I am wondering to know if it is possible to use a Custom Metadata Type inside an Email Template.
I'm moving from Custom Setting to Custom Metadata Type and this feature could be great.

Regarding the Custom Setting, only if we use a Hierarchy Custom Setting we can do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom metadata types in SObject Formula fields so the following works fine (example):

**On Contact SObject**

New formula field (text) `Foo__c`  with value

```
$CustomMetadata.MyCustomMetadataType__mdt.SomeDeveloperNameOfRow.SomeFieldName__c
```

**In email template:**

```
Hello {!Foo__c}
```

Comment: can't be used directly?

Comment: @AdityaVijay - I just tried again using a classic email template - not supported