# Custom label/settings/metadata in email templates

Tags: email-template, customsetting, custom-metadata, customlabel

Is that possible to use a Custom Label/Settings/Metadata inside an Email Templates
by referencing? instead of creating a formula field as it was suggested [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/261302/using-custom-metadata-type-in-email-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Plain Text or HTML template, you need a formula, but in a Visualforce template, you can use the [global variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global.htm) directly to access labels, settings, metadata, etc.

Comment: I thought things might have changed in Salesforce world but looks like still the same :) so I have no other choice but to use formula field inside the email templates?

Comment: @NickKahn as far as I can tell, yes. They haven't updated classic email template in ages.

Comment: @sfdcfox - I have a somewhat different answer here

Answer (score 1):

At least for HTML templates, the following merge fields:

| Global Variable | Renders | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `$API.xxx` | NO |  |
| `$CustomMetadata.xxx` | NO |  |
| `$Label.xxx` | YES | [1] |
| `$ObjectType.xxx` | NO |  |
| `$Organization.xxx` | YES | [1] |
| `$Permission.xxx` | YES | [1] |
| `$Profile.xxx` | YES | [1] |
| `$Setup.xxx` | YES | [1] |
| `$User.xxx` | NO |  |
| `$UserRole.xxx` | YES | [1] |

Where renders YES means:

- When email preview is sent to recipient
- When email is sent by automation or code
- When email is sent by Email Publisher (e.g. send email from a Case)
- When you use `renderStoredEmailTemplate()` method

***Notes***

[1] No rendering is done in the Classic Email previewer; Email Publisher will render in the preview (e.g. sending an email from a Case)

---

I did not look at other Global variables as they are mostly for use in a Visualforce Context where they are defined by definition to work in VF emails